# How to change digits of the page number to Persian or Arabic in Office Word 365

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I have a MS Word `docx` file. I want to see digits in Farsi or Persian. Therefore, in the menu `Word Options>Advanced` I have set the `Numeral` to `Context`.

[image: Picture of my settings for seeing digits based on the context]

While the digits are changed to Farsi or Persian in my body text, the page numbers are not changed in Microsoft Office Word 365. Not only the page numbers have this problem in the header and the footer but also this problem exists in the `Table of Content`. Following picture shows how digits changed in the text body but not in the page numbers inside the *TOC*.

[image: This picture shows how digits changed in the text body but not in the page numbers inside the *TOC*]

I would like to have all these page numbers in Farsi. Not only in my header and footer but also in my *TOC*.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this issue is a bug, I think it is related to MS Word setting. I never noticed this issue in office 365, as I normally use Office 2013 and this problem does not exist there. 
However, I provided a solution for you. I modified some fonts and replaced the `0123456789` with `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`, so if you install these fonts in your system and use them for the page number and table of content then your problem can be solved.

[image: illustration of solved page number issue in Persian or Arabic documents]

You can download the fonts from the following repository: https://github.com/MJZSoft/PersianPageNUmber

However, still I cannot believe this is a bug in new MS office release and I think it is more or less a setting problem, although I couldn't find any clue regarding the misconfiguration as I have the same problem in MS Word 365. In the meanwhile you can leverage my solution, while I hope some MS office expert guide us regarding the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works for me.

Comment: That Saved me. Thaaank Yooooou